# Using arcpy.da.SearchCursor to sort field in attribute table by ascending order

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table, cursor, sorting

I am using ArcMap 10.6 with Python 2.7.14 with ArcPy.

I want to sort a field named `Seq_ID` in my attribute table by ascending order using ArcPy.

I believe I have to use arcpy.da.SearchCursor.

Here is my code snippet:

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points, fields, sql_clause=(None,'ORDER BY Seq_ID ASC'):
     arcpy.AddMessage("")
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage("")
```

However, after using this snippet above, my table is not sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a search cursor to READ your dataset and applying a sort whilst reading it, you are not editing it!

If you want to permanently sort rows in a table you need to use the [SORT](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm) tool, this will create a new dataset sorted.